# Add custom field to Wordpress register and check if it matches an entery in database

Tags: wordpress

I have a database "Codes" of enteries like 00123, 01392 etc.

I want to add an field to my Wordpress register and check if it matches an entery in my database "Codes" at the user register. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Action hook

```
add_action ( 'show_user_profile', 'my_fields' );
add_action ( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_fields' );

function my_fields ( $user )
{
?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="twitter">Twitter</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="twitter" id="twitter" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'twitter', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description">Please enter your Twitter username.</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}

add_action ( 'personal_options_update', 'my_fields_save' );
add_action ( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_fields_save' );

function my_fields_save( $user_id )
{
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    /* Copy and paste this line for additional fields. Make sure to change 'twitter' to the field ID. */
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'twitter', $_POST['twitter'] );
}
```